# Haskell - List of instances of a Typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm fairly new to Haskell, and to get better I'm trying to make a simple web server. I wanted to make how I represent pages extendable, so my idea was to make webpages be a list of Renderable data (like how you can make a list of objects that implement a certain interface in Java) where Renderable is

```
class Renderable a where
    render :: a -> IO String
```

Unfortunately I learned that lists MUST be a concrete type, so I can only make a list of one type of Renderable data. Also it seems impossible to create data that is constrained by a typeclass, so I can't make something like RenderList data. My temporary solution has been like this:

```
myPage =
    [render $ someData
    ,render $ someMoreData
    ,render $ someOtherData
    ...
    ]
```

but this feels awkward, makes the use of a typeclass have no benefit, and feels like there should be a better way. So I'm wondering what ways could I restructure what I have to be cleaner, more in line with standard Haskell practices, and still be easily extendable?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a preexisting web framework?  Yesod, Snap, Happstack, all good choices.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski I don't want to because I'm using this as a way to learn Haskell.

Comment: To be completely honest: low level web programming in Haskell is hard!  The correct way to do IO is still not completely understood and programming it properly in a functional style is an art.  This sounds like a better way to just become pissed off at Haskell rather than learning it.  I would still contend that you can learn all the core features, along with getting something "real" off the ground, and be much less frustrated if you use a pre baked web framework.

Comment: P.s., please note that in the example you give, you can easily clean it up by using `map` over the list.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Maybe Web Server was the wrong term. I'm new to web development, so I don't know the terms that well. Essentially what I'm making is an application that is run from a cgi-script, which is run using a RewriteRule in my website's .htaccess (this is on my university's server). My application then creates html which is printed. So I'm probably just calling this by the wrong name (if you know what that type of application is called please share).

Comment: "you can easily clean it up by using `map` over the list"

But what would you map over? You can't create a list with different types of data, which is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, but using the existential type approach outlined in the answer given, you *can*...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to implement an object-oriented style of design.  In Java, for example, you'd have a `List<Renderable>` and you'd be all set.  This design style is a little bit less natural in Haskell; you need to create a wrapper type for a bounded existential as demonstrated on the Haskell wiki page for [existential types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type#Dynamic_dispatch_mechanism_of_OOP).  For example:

```
class Renderable_ a where
  render :: a -> IO String

data Renderable = forall a. Renderable_ a => Renderable a
instance Renderable_ Renderable where
  render (Renderable a) = render a
```

You can then have a list of `Renderable`, which you can render however you like.  Like I said, though, that is sort of an OO style which is less natural in Haskell.  You can probably avoid this by rethinking your data structures.  You say that you "wanted to make how you represent pages extendable"; consider other ways of doing that instead.

Unrelated: I'm guessing `render` doesn't need to produce an `IO String` action.  Try to keep `IO` out of the core of your design, if you can.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this page on haskell [heterogenous collections](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections).
It provides ideas of several approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the one that seems closest to what I want to do - 4. Existential types - still seems to have the same problems my solution has. I don't understand how what they have done to create hlist is any better than making hlist with String and show instead of Showable and pack.